# Extract this nested ternary operation into an independent statement

Tags: javascript

I am getting the above error with the example code below, I am quite new to nested ternary operations so your help would be appreciated.
Example code below:

```
Car4 = {
  data: {
    CoverBasis: item.coverBasis() || "Client",
    IncludeInPackage: item.canBeIncludedInPackage() ?
      (item.includeInPackage() && totalPolicies > 1 ? "Yes" : "No") : "No"
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't need this to be nested, it is 'yes' if all are true, or 'no' if any is false (in order) `item.canBeIncludedInPackage() && item.includeInPackage() && totalPolicies > 1 ? "Yes" : "No";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error tells you to move the nester ternary operator `totalPolicies > 1 ? "Yes" : "No"`  in the separated variable, like this:

```
const areTotalPoliciesBiggerOne = totalPolicies > 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
Car4 = {
  data: {
    CoverBasis: item.coverBasis() || "Client",
    IncludeInPackage: item.canBeIncludedInPackage() ?
      (item.includeInPackage() && areTotalPoliciesBiggerOne) : "No"
  }
};
```

Comment: Why did you think `item.includeInPackage()` is not part of the nested ternary?

Answer (score -3):

You need to put yes or not in a `<div></div>`

```
 `totalPolicies > 1 ? <div>"Yes"</div>: 
<div>No</div>`
```