# Nested ternary into an independent statement typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting the above error with the example code below, I am quite new to nested ternary operations so your help would be appreciated. Example code below:

```
  get notEmptyProduct(): string[] {
    return this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts && this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts.length ? this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts : this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts && this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts.length ? this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts : [];
  }
```

**Extract this nested ternary operation into an independent statement.**

Comment: I think you just need to properly wrap in parentheses to make sure it is executed in you expected precedence.

Comment: notEmptyProduct(): string[] {
    return this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts && this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts.length ? this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts : (this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts && this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts.length ? this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts : []);
  }

Comment: Can you write an answer please

Comment: oh sorry, just notice the bold text is the error you are getting. what is suggested is to extract nested ternary operator to a separate variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769991/extract-this-nested-ternary-operation-into-an-independent-statement

Comment: This is not a TypeScript error. It sounds more like a linter warning. What linter are you using, and which rule is this specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and how javascript process [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values. The last empty array is to make sure that it returns an empty array in case of other failures to comply with method's return type. This is better than having nested ternary operators I believe.

```
  get notEmptyProduct(): string[] {
    return (this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts?.length  && this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts) || (this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts?.length && this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts) || [];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving nested ternary to a separate variable.

```js
notEmptyProduct(): string[] { 
const nestedTernaryResult = this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts && this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts.length ? this.contractSettings.allowedControlEstimateProducts : [];
return this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts &&  this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts.length ?     this.contractSettings.allowedRegularEstimateProducts : nestedTernaryResult;
}
```